# Visual Studio 2013 stopped working. Tried a reinstall and it still wont work

Tags: visual-studio-2013

[image]

A few days ago visual studio stopped working, I tried to reinstall and I got this message after the reinstall. I don't know how to fix it.

EDIT:
[image]

I have added the activity log, i hope that helps

Comment: have you tried redownloding it?

Comment: tried that, it didnt work

Answer (score 1):

Try start VS2013 with /Log

Like: devenv /log
That will log all actions to the default path of

%APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Version\ActivityLog.xml

Perhaps it can give a hint what is going wrong.

Or with a /SafeMode and see if VS2013 can run at all?

Comment: i did a disk cleanup last week, I think thats why it wont open. And i cant do a system restore to an early enough point

Comment: What about /SafeMode, can you then start VS2013? - And perhaps Windows Event Log  - Application

Comment: Okay, so my PkgDef is encountering a collision

Comment: PkgDef are "Extensions" for VS2013, like 
"VSCommands for Visual Studio" etc.

Perhaps there is an extension that prevents VS2013 to startup?